How to count objective function and gradient calls of LineSearches functions in Julia (a la Optim package)
I have no experience with Julia so apologies if this is a very basic/boad question. I want to implement my own optimiser (Projected Gradient Descent) that will make use of various line search algorithms from the LineSearches package. Since the optimisers in the Optim package don't quite do want I need, I'm tryig to use the approach describe in the documentation here. However- as this is the metric I need - is there a simple, quick way (e.g. by modifying the example optimiser from the link above) to output the number of times the objective and the grad functions are called, like optimize from Optim package does?

If you use the NLPModels interface to access your model then counters will be incremented for you. See https://jso.dev/NLPModels.jl/dev/ or https://jso.dev/tutorials/ maybe
